# Can I store IP addresses as integers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integer, ip

I record the IP address of users. Since IP addresses include periods, I'm storing them as strings. But I'd like to try to save space on my server by trying to save them as integers.

I considered doing this:

```
@user_ip = request.remote_ip.delete(".").to_i
```

Which would convert, for example, "127.0.0.1" to `127001`.

But I'm concerned two different IP addresses could be saved as the same integer under that method.

Is that possible? If so, is there a better way to save IP addresses as integers?

Comment: ip4v addresses will fit in an unsigned int -- each octet is one byte.  you'll have to do some conversion.  But it's probably  not really worth it, it's not a particularly friendly format to query for (and doesn't really work at all for ipv6).

Comment: It may be worth using your server's [IP address type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-net-types.html), if it has one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard way to do these conversions (in C-language) is called [`inet_aton`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton) (ascii to number) and [`inet_ntoa`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa) (number to ascii). The Ruby equivalent methods are included in [`IPAddr`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html):

```
require 'ipaddr'

IPAddr.new("192.168.0.1").to_i
 => 3232235521 

IPAddr.new(3232235521, Socket::AF_INET).to_s
 => "192.168.0.1"
```

But as others pointer out here too, querying the number representations from a database is not always practical. However MySQL for example does allow you to use the `inet_ntoa/aton` functions directly in queries:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html

This is useful if you want to start to filter and query IP addresses with netmasks for instance. See here for more examples how to set it up and how to run queries this way:
http://www.finnie.org/2007/12/05/mysql-and-cidr-selection/

Comment: It's also trivially easy to use Rails' `serialize` feature to automatically convert the IPAddr to an integer and back when writing to/reading from the database. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @Jordan, would what you suggested above work for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524506/get-ipaddr-instance-from-its-json-representation) situation?  Also, here is a little more info: https://github.com/liveeditor/draftsman/issues/43

Answer (score 1):

In the way you described it would be impossible to "re-IP" it because you wouldn't know where to put the periods back.  Could be 127.0.0.1 or 12.70.0.1 etc.  You could use four separate columns for each of the sections and the integer size would only have to be 9 or 8 unsigned to represent 0-255 if you're that concerned about space.

Then put them together `ip_col_1+".".ip_col_2+"."+ip_col_3+"."+ip_col_4` to actually use it.

I can't really think of this making much of a difference except making your code more complex, as the comments mentioned.