# Get IPAddr instance from its json representation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql, devise

How can I get back an `IPAddr` instance from its json representation?

## Context:

I'm working on a Rails application that uses the `draftsman` gem.  Essentially, when one makes a change to a record in the database and that ruby model `has_drafts`, instead of making the change to the record right away, a draft of the changes and the resulting record is saved in the drafts table until one `publish!`es that draft.  Then the changes are made to the actual record.  Pretty neat :)

The drafts table holds the object that would result from allowing the changes to happen in a json column in a postgres table.

I'm also using Devise and my user model uses the `trackable` module, which includes a `current_sign_in_ip` as well as a `last_sign_in_ip` of column type `inet`.

## Problem:

`inet` type columns in my user table, as well as the rest of the `User` object, are being stored in the drafts table created by the `draftsman` gem in a single json column called `object`.  `reify`ing the object from its draft does not succeed in this case because of the following reason: `IPAddr` instances have a json representation that the `IPAddr` class is incapable of perceiving.  For example, `IPAddr` instances in ruby respond to `to_json`, which gives me something that looks like this: `"\"family\":2,\"addr\":2130706433,\"mask_addr\":4294967295}"`.  These instances also respond to `to_s` and give me something like this: `"127.0.0.1"`.  Unfortunately, the `IPAddr` class doesn't seem to know how to bring itself back from json from what I can tell:

```rb
[277, 286] in /home/jake/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/draftsman-1bd3c797d540/lib/draftsman/model.rb
   277:               data = {
   278:                 :item      => self,
   279:                 :whodunnit => Draftsman.whodunnit,
   280:                 :object    => object_attrs_for_draft_record
   281:               }
=> 282:               data = merge_metadata_for_draft(data)
   283: 
   284:               # If there's already a draft, update it.
   285:               if send(self.class.draft_association_name).present?
   286:                 data[:object_changes] = changes_for_draftsman if track_object_changes_for_draft?

(byebug) data[:object]['current_sign_in_ip']
#<IPAddr: IPv4:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255>
(byebug) data[:object]['current_sign_in_ip'].to_json
"{\"family\":2,\"addr\":2130706433,\"mask_addr\":4294967295}"

(byebug) IPAddr.new(data[:object]['current_sign_in_ip'].to_s)
#<IPAddr: IPv4:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255>
(byebug) IPAddr.new(data[:object]['current_sign_in_ip'].to_json)
*** IPAddr::InvalidAddressError Exception: invalid address

nil
(byebug)
```

I figured posting this question to StackOverflow would get some attention to this issue, but I also submitted a github [issue](https://github.com/liveeditor/draftsman/issues/43) on the `Draftsman` github page if any other information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but if you read my comment below d_ethier's answer you can see that `IPAddr` doesn't really know anything about JSON.

However you can monkey patch it to understand JSON like so:

```
require 'active_model'
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'ipaddr'

class IPAddr
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

  attr_accessor :addr, :mask_addr, :family

  def attributes=(hash)
    hash.each do |key, value|
      send("#{key}=", value)
    end
  end

  def attributes
    instance_values
  end
end   

p i = IPAddr.new('127.0.0.1')
p j = i.to_json
p IPAddr.new.from_json(j)
```

Output:

```
#<IPAddr: IPv4:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255>
"{\"family\":2,\"addr\":2130706433,\"mask_addr\":4294967295}"
#<IPAddr: IPv4:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255>
```

Source:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/from_json

Comment: This definitely answers my question as well as gives me an idea on how to move forward

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is something else.

`IPAddr.new(data[:object]['current_sign_in_ip'].to_s)` is not altering the contents of `data[:object]['current_sign_in_ip']`, so there shouldn't be a reason to "convert" it back.

In fact, `data[:object]['current_sign_in_ip']` is already an IPAddr object. Wrapping it in IPAddr.new is redundant.

I suspect you're trying to do something else and this is just your description, so without seeing your code, it's hard to help.

If this is the case, you could work around it by creating a variable for the original IPAddr instance and use that later on.

```
original_ipaddr = data[:object]['current_sign_in_ip']
... rest of your code
IPAddr.new(data[:object]['current_sign_in_ip'].to_json)
IPAddr.new(original_ipaddr.to_s)
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear about this.  I know it is already in the form I want it at the point I spit it out in byebug.  It is when it is saved to the drafts table.  The object is stored in json, and `IPAddr` instances have a json representation that I can not recover the `IPAddr` representation of after I read it back out of the database.  Putting it in a `IPAddr.new(...)` call was purely just to demonstrate that the `IPAddr` class doesn't seem to know how to perceive its own json representation.

Comment: @JakeSmith The JSON representation comes from the Rails ActiveSupport method `to_json`. `IPAddr` knows nothing about JSON and the only reason `to_json` is available is because ActiveSupport has monkey patched all Objects to respond to `to_json` (which dumps their instance variables into a Hash). Now then, most ActiveRecord models know how to reload themselves from JSON representations, but IPAddr is not an ActiveRecord model. Without digging further into draftsman source it's difficult to really know what is going on. The problem is most likely in draftsman though, and certainly not in IPAddr.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and info!  That all makes sense.  I noticed just yesterday that the `to_json` method only behaved this way with my app because I tried to replicate the issue just in `irb` and got different results.  I also think this should be fixed in that gem and I'm trying to understand this all better so that I can potentially help get it fixed.  I would like to start contributing to open source software in the RoR world, but I need to get better at understanding the language as well as the Rails ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone sees this, we fixed this in ActiveSupport

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40932
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e7d207f02fe8bf6e351de7da106839b0ab14bbea

If using Rails, we should be able to fix this with an initializer:

```rb
class IPAddr
  def as_json(options = nil)
    to_s
  end
end
```